# C++ objects to Lua [ Overloading operator= ]

Tags: c++, lua, overloading, operator-keyword

Using the Lua API, I can create C++ classes in lua, for which I have redefined some operators (__tostring, __gc, __len, etc.). Everything works correctly, but but such objects are pointers in lua script.

Code in lua script:

```
local vec = Vector2:new(500, 500)

local table = {
    new_vec = vec   -- A pointer to the object is created, not a copy of it.
}

print(tostring(vec))
print(tostring(table.new_vec))

vec.x = 100
vec.y = 100

print(tostring(vec))
print(tostring(table.new_vec))

table.new_vec.x = 200
table.new_vec.y = 200

print(tostring(vec))
print(tostring(table.new_vec))
```

Output:
500
500

100
100

200
200

But I would like a copy of the object to be stored in a table, and the changes only concern it.
Is it possible to reload the operator=, something like __replace?

Comment: Even if you overload `operator=`, you will still have the same object in your table as outside, so it doesn't solve the problem. You'd want to make a userdata that has copy-by-value semantics, and I'm not sure that's possible without modifying the Lua engine itself to add `Vector2` as a new core type.

Comment: To avoid accidents, consider making `Vector2` immutable, so you can't assign to `x` and `y` but are instead forced to create a new instance. You can create helper functions `with_x`, `with_y` to make this easy... but I think you'll find you rarely need them.

Comment: Since I need the ability to modify the object, I just added the copy() method and call it if necessary.